# Most recent value per column with multiple column group by and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, indexing, where-clause

Given this 2 million+ entry table,ID auto incrementing, and index1(MainId,SubID,Column1)
index2(MainId,SubID,Column2):

```
ID  MainID  SubID  Column1    Column2 
--------------------------------------
1     1       A   1A_data_1           
2     1       A              1A_data_2
3     2       B   2B_data_1           
4     2       B              2B_data_2
5     1       A   ignore_me             
6     1       A              1A_data_3
```

I can get the row ID that contains the desired column value using indexes with:

```
Select max(ID) 
From table where column1 is not null and column1 <>'ignore_me'
Group By MainID,SubID

Select max(id) 
From table where column2 is not null and column2 <>'ignore_me'
Group By MainID,SubID
```

But what I can't do is find an efficient way to join these against a MainID,SubID group by to get these results:

```
MainID  SubID  Column1    Column2
--------------------------------
  1       A   1A_data_1  1A_data_3
  2       B   2B_data_1  2B_data_2
```

I've tried a lot of different approaches, but nothing that doesnt take forever. Do I need another index? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple as the group by queries are super fast. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check the execution plan on your other approaches, they will indicate if an index is needed or not (it is not always correct).  And if you don't have it already, give Red Gate's Plan Explorer a go, very nice (and free) tool.

Comment: First off, thanks for the reply and I will check Red Gate's Plan Explore out.  For the record, I have checked execution plans and cant find a good one. I've even run every bad one I can think of just in case EXPLAIN is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the two IDs in a single query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  MainID,
  SubID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 <> 'ignore_me' THEN ID END) AS ID1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 'ignore_me' THEN ID END) AS ID2
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  MainID,
  SubID
;
```

You could also explicitly add `AND ColumnN IS NOT NULL` to the WHEN conditions but that's not necessary, NULL values would be ignored anyway.

Now you can simply do two left joins with the above subquery as a derived table:

```
SELECT
  tm.MainID,
  tm.SubID,
  t1.Column1,
  t2.Column2
FROM (
  SELECT
    MainID,
    SubID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 <> 'ignore_me' THEN ID END) AS ID1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 'ignore_me' THEN ID END) AS ID2
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY
    MainID,
    SubID
) tm
  LEFT JOIN atable t1 ON tm.ID1 = t1.ID
  LEFT JOIN atable t2 ON tm.ID2 = t2.ID
;
```

---

*UPDATE (converting to a view, in answer to comments)*

So far I can see only one alternative that would be VIEW-friendly:

```
SELECT
  MainID,
  SubID,
  (
    SELECT Column1
    FROM atable
    WHERE MainID = t.MainID
      AND SubID  = t.SubID
      AND Column1 <> 'ignore_me'
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS ID1,
  (
    SELECT Column2
    FROM atable
    WHERE MainID = t.MainID
      AND SubID  = t.SubID
      AND Column2 <> 'ignore_me'
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS ID2
FROM atable t
GROUP BY
  MainID,
  SubID
;
```

This query may be slower than the previous one, though: it uses two correlated subqueries, and I'm not sure if queries (or, in particular, views) with correlated subqueries can be efficient in MySQL. Proper indexing might help. In general, you'll probably need to test this for yourself.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. This works better than what I was doing... joining the two separate queries against the table. Any idea how to do it without the subquery in the FROM clause?  I'd like it to be a view.

Comment: Can't think of anything better at the moment than using correlated subqueries. Please see my update.

Comment: As you suspected, the 2 correlated subqueries are not efficient with the current indexes.  Making the conditional aggregation query a view itself and creating a second view works though. Thanks again.